# DatabaseError while connecting cx_Oracle to SQL Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue when I am trying to connect to SQL Database. I have Installed cx_oracle using command: python -m pip install cx_Oracle (version 6.0.2). I use Python 2.7 version 32-bit on Windows 7. SQL DB version is 12.1.0.2.0.

I got the following error when I was trying to connect to SQL Database:
DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher
Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Is there a way to fix the problem without upgrading the oracle to an higher version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version is the Oracle client  ?

Comment: I have Installed Oracle client using the command: python -m pip install Instant Oracle client. I could not install Oracle Client because my system couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement Oracle.